# Order of operations in awk?

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to use awk to do two things. I want to separate a list into three separate lists and convert 1 or 2 columns of each to a regular expression. When I pipe awk to itself, ie select my items in my list and then use awk to do the substitutions, it appends 1s to the list items.

I figure I need to not pipe awk to itself and instead do all of this in a single call to awk.

```
AH??0*,*,ARRAY RESISTIVITY,RESISTIVITY
AHD*,*,MEASURED DEPTH,REFERENCE
AI*,*,ACOUSTIC IMPEDANCE COMPRESSIONAL,GEOPHYSICAL SYNTHETICS
AI_AVG_HOR_SIG,*,ACOUSTIC IMPEDANCE,ACOUSTIC
*,FOO,BAR,BLEH
```

List one would be lines like line 4, with no wildcards in column one, replacing wildcards in column 2.

List two would be for lines 1,2 and 3 in a separate list and will need to do substitutions on columns 1 and 2.

Lastly, I need to do a similar thing for line 5 in a separate list.

I am able to get this lists doing this.

Line 4: `awk -F \, '$1!~/([\*\?])/' file.txt`
Lines 1-3: `awk -F \, '$1~/([\*\?])/' file.txt`
Line 5: `awk -F \, '$1~/^\*$/' file.txt`

My subs are * => .* and ? => [0-9].

When I attempt to use gsub like this `awk -F \, 'gsub(/\*/,".*",$2) $1!~/([\*\?])/' OFS=, file.txt`, the list comes back funky with unexpected results. I feel as though there is a fundamental thing I don't understand about awk with regard to stacking operations.

Halp!

Comment: You need to put that `gsub` in an action block. `{gsub(...)}`. Right now it is a pattern. So it performs its task and then tells awk to print the current line. If you only want that gsub when the `$1~....` pattern matches then you want to put the gsub in an action block for that pattern (and you will need to add `print` as well).

Comment: That worked for me. The only issue I have now is that this

`awk -F \, '$1~/[\*\?]/ && $1!~/^\*$/' {gsub(/\*/,".*",$1) ; gsub(/\?/,"[0-9]",$1) ; gsub(/\*/,".*",$2);print} OFS=, file.txt` results in an error. Likely because I'm doing two regex comparisons. Not sure how to get around that.

Comment: You ended the awk script (single quoted string) too early. The single quote needs to be after the final `;print}` not after `$1!~/^\*$/`.

Comment: Thanks Etan! I ended up using:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{if($1~/[\*\?]/ && $1!~/^\*$/){ gsub(/\*/,".*",$1); gsub(/\?/,"[0-9]",$1); gsub(/\*/,".*",$2); print; } }' OFS=, file.txt`

Comment: You could hoist the tests back out to an action instead of using `if ()` but I don't know that that matters in any way but stylistically. I'd also pick one way of setting variables, either `BEGIN` or from the command line, but again that's just style.

Comment: @juanschwartz : no need to backslash those 2 inside a cage : `$1 ~ /[*?]/` more than suffices. And since you already have the `BEGIN { }` section, perhaps `FS = OFS = ","` would be cleaner ?

Answer (score 1):

What I write here is not the solution of your question. It is just an exercise of
reorganization of your versions... (for you to complete :).
Some of @Etan wise suggestions are still missing. (Stylistic concerns can save us lots of time).

awk (or any one-liner solutions) gets confusing in it exceeds some 30 chars.
Quotes, etc become difficult.

You can (should?) write it in a file (a.awk) with proper indentation, comments, vertical symmetries:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN                          { FS="," ; OFS=","     }

$1 ~ /[\*\?]/ && $1 !~ /^\*$/  { gsub(/\*/, ".*"   ,$1 );
                                 gsub(/\?/, "[0-9]",$1 );
                                 gsub(/\*/, ".*"   ,$2 );
                                 print; }
```

and use it as `awk -f a.awk  inputfile`

The current behavior is:

```
echo 'AH??0*,*,ARRAY RESISTIVITY,RESISTIVITY
AHD*,*,MEASURED DEPTH,REFERENCE
AI*,*,ACOUSTIC IMPEDANCE COMPRESSIONAL,GEOPHYSICAL SYNTHETICS
AI_AVG_HOR_SIG,*,ACOUSTIC IMPEDANCE,ACOUSTIC
*,FOO,BAR,BLEH' | awk -f /tmp/a1

AH[0-9][0-9]0.*,.*,ARRAY RESISTIVITY,RESISTIVITY
AHD.*,.*,MEASURED DEPTH,REFERENCE
AI.*,.*,ACOUSTIC IMPEDANCE COMPRESSIONAL,GEOPHYSICAL SYNTHETICS
```

Comment: I appreciate that. I was able to feed off of Etan's comments and gain a bit more info on awk as I haven't had to use it very often. However, after diving in, I can see where it would save me tons of time in the future...